How to add Distortion Coefficients to Unity Camera?
I am currently working on a Unity Project with HDRP to export Images for the training of a Machine Learning Model. Therefore Unity needs to ouput images with the same distortion as my physical camera does.
My physical camera has the following distortion coefficients:
[[-2.47452838e-01  6.46654811e-02 -1.27455022e-05 -9.08803171e-04 -7.60635980e-03]]
Now I want to apply those distortions to my unity camera. How do I do that and is there a simpler way than writing my own shader for it?
